# Probability in a multinomial regression

Tags: probability, interpretation, stata, multinomial-logit

I have the following output from a multinomial logit, where an individual can be employed as a university professor, a government employee or a high school teacher. Can I determine if within those who are school teachers or government employees what the likelihood/probability for a person with specific characteristics (say male with graduate parents) is a government employee?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is easiest to do in Stata with the `margins` postestimation command.

Take for example this `mlogit` using the `nlsw88` data (in Stata V16.1).

```
. sysuse nlsw88
(NLSW, 1988 extract)

. mlogit race i.(collgrad c_city)

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -1419.9917  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -1337.1507  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -1335.1248  
Iteration 3:   log likelihood = -1335.1238  
Iteration 4:   log likelihood = -1335.1238  

Multinomial logistic regression                 Number of obs     =      2,246
                                                LR chi2(4)        =     169.74
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -1335.1238                     Pseudo R2         =     0.0598

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         race |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
white         |  (base outcome)
--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
black         |
     collgrad |
college grad  |  -.6145886   .1276527    -4.81   0.000    -.8647833   -.3643939
     1.c_city |   1.272722   .1035434    12.29   0.000     1.069781    1.475664
        _cons |  -1.342776   .0676474   -19.85   0.000    -1.475362    -1.21019
--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
other         |
     collgrad |
college grad  |   .4077159   .4183986     0.97   0.330    -.4123303    1.227762
     1.c_city |   .2176396    .448688     0.49   0.628    -.6617728    1.097052
        _cons |  -4.318084   .2660075   -16.23   0.000    -4.839449   -3.796719
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can get all combinations of probabilities for each outcome across the `collgrad` and `c_city` factors like:

```
. margins collgrad#c_city

Adjusted predictions                            Number of obs     =      2,246
Model VCE    : OIM

1._predict   : Pr(race==white), predict(pr outcome(1))
2._predict   : Pr(race==black), predict(pr outcome(2))
3._predict   : Pr(race==other), predict(pr outcome(3))

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                         |            Delta-method
                         |     Margin   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
_predict#collgrad#c_city |
   1#not college grad#0  |   .7846551   .0112071    70.01   0.000     .7626896    .8066207
   1#not college grad#1  |   .5131075   .0214106    23.97   0.000     .4711436    .5550715
       1#college grad#0  |   .8611312   .0145508    59.18   0.000     .8326121    .8896503
       1#college grad#1  |   .6539476   .0275329    23.75   0.000     .5999841     .707911
   2#not college grad#0  |    .204889   .0110044    18.62   0.000     .1833208    .2264572
   2#not college grad#1  |   .4783927   .0214567    22.30   0.000     .4363383     .520447
       2#college grad#0  |   .1216177   .0134104     9.07   0.000     .0953339    .1479015
       2#college grad#1  |   .3297666   .0273209    12.07   0.000     .2762187    .3833145
   3#not college grad#0  |   .0104558   .0027482     3.80   0.000     .0050694    .0158423
   3#not college grad#1  |   .0084998   .0035388     2.40   0.016     .0015638    .0154358
       3#college grad#0  |   .0172511   .0062355     2.77   0.006     .0050299    .0294724
       3#college grad#1  |   .0162859   .0072031     2.26   0.024     .0021681    .0304037
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Using this table of results, I can infer that, for example, that the probability of being White when the respondent is a college graduate and does *not* live in a city center (i.e., `1#not college grad#0`) is .78.

The same logic could be applied to your data with the gender and parental education variables in the screenshot.